# Creating custom "things" menu in WordPress Admin

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin, taxonomy

I think WordPress have this capability, because I've seen this before, but I'm not being able to find it. I would like to know how to create my own set of custom "things" in a WordPress site. I'll explain:

I'm working on a WordPress website and I would like to be able to create a new Admin menu named "Files" where the user could just upload PDF files, just like if he was creating a new Post, with that same interface, and this uploaded files would be listed to download on a page of the Website, just like as if they were a list of "Last Posts". This new menu item would have to be placed between "Posts" and "Pages".

I've been looking to study for the Taxonomy WordPress concept but it does not seem to be what I'm looking for.

How can I create a custom type of "things" menu in WordPress Admin?

Comment: There are a ton of ways to accomplish this but as you seem to have limited proficiency with code/wordpress I'd say probably using a plugin to create a custom post type is your best bet.  Check out the "Types" plugin.  You don't need to worry about taxonomies - they are essentially custom category types for custom post types.

Comment: Once you have your custom post type (e.g. "PDFs") set up with whatever plugin you use, you need to set up a custom file upload field (also can be done with Types), then you need to create a page template that will list them, probably using a custom `WP_Query` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) and custom loop that uses `get_post_meta` to get the file url from the custom upload field you set up for that post type.

Answer (score -1):

add_action('admin_menu', 'demo_menu');

```
 function demo_menu() {
    $page_title = 'page title';
    $menu_title = 'menu title';
    $capability = 'administrator';
    $parent_menu_slug = 'demo-shipping';
    $sub_menu_slug = 'demo-shipping-settings';
    $sub_menu_slug1 = 'demo-inventory-update';
    $function = 'demo_shipping_display';
    $function1 = 'demo_inventory_update';
    $icon_url = 'dashicons-admin-generic';
    $position = 24;

    add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $parent_menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position);
    add_submenu_page($parent_menu_slug, 'demo', 'Add Inventory', $capability, $sub_menu_slug, $function);
    add_submenu_page($parent_menu_slug, 'demo', 'Update Inventory', $capability, $sub_menu_slug1, $function1);
  }

  function demo_shipping_display() {
      include 'demo-template.php';
   }
```